# Polar molecule in external electric field - problem with the Fourier transform

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, fourier-transform, probability

I have a problem  where I am considering a polar molecule with dipole vector $\vec{p}$ moving in a plane and exposed to an electric field, so that the interaction potential is:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
V_{e x t}=-\boldsymbol{E}(t) \cdot \boldsymbol{p}=-E(t) p \cos \theta
\end{equation}
The electric field is small so that the probability distribution of the angle between the dipole vector and the electric field can be seen as:
$$\tag{2}
P(\theta, t)=P_{0}+\tilde{P}(\theta, t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}+\tilde{P}(\theta, t)
$$
I want to find an expression for this probability. I made a separation of variables $\tilde{P}(\theta, t)=\cos \theta g(t)$ and obtained the following differential equation from the Fokker-Planck equation:
$$\tag{3}
\frac{d g}{d t}+D_{r} g=\varepsilon_{0} e^{i\omega t}
$$
Where $\varepsilon_0$ and $D_r$ are constants and I assume an oscillating field, $E=E_0 e^{i\omega t}$. I was told by the professor that I can make a Fourier transform to solve for $\hat{g}(\omega)$, where $\hat{g}$ is the Fourier transform of $g(t)$. It is easy to find that the Fourier transform of $\frac{dg}{dt}$ can be written $i\omega \hat{g}(\omega)$. However, I cannot see how I can make a Fourier transform of the right-hand side of eq. (3), since the integral seems to blow up? Can someone see where I am going wrong, or what to do from here?

Comment: Fourier transform of RHS is the Dirac delta distribution $\delta(k+\omega)$, k is the transformed variable.

Comment: In which case the Fourier transform of $g(t)$ becomes 
$$\hat{g}(\omega)=\frac{\varepsilon_0 \delta(k+\omega)}{i\omega+D_r}$$
But I don't see how that makes sense, so I believe there is a mistake but I don't know where.

Comment: Use different notations for $\omega$ in the electric field and for the transformed variable. You're mixing them up

Comment: $\hat{g}(k)=\frac{\varepsilon_0\delta(k+\omega)}{ik+D_r}$. It doesn't change the problem though. But thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fourier transforming $(3)$ yields
$$
\hat{g}(k)=\frac{\varepsilon_{0} \delta(k+\omega)}{i k+D_{r}}
$$

Inverse Transform would give -
$$g(t)=\int e^{ikt}\hat{g}(k)dk=\int e^{ikt}\frac{\varepsilon_{0} \delta(k+\omega)}{i k+D_{r}}dk$$
$$=\frac{\varepsilon_{0} e^{-i\omega t}}{-i\omega+D_{r}}\tag{E1}$$

It can be verified that this expression satisfies eqn $(3)$

Note : $(E1)$ is a particular solution of $(3)$. General solution is
$$g(t)=Ce^{-D_rt}+\frac{\varepsilon_{0} e^{-i\omega t}}{-i\omega+D_{r}}$$

where $e^{-D_rt}$ is the solution to the homogeneous version of $(3)$ and C is a constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!